# backbone circle rotation with text

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am new to backbone...
I would like to increase the size of circle...
can you guys tell me how to double the size of circle...
providing my code below...
and even i wanted it to rotate slowly..and how to enter text inside the circle...

```
.box {
  border-radius: 300px;
  width: 20px; height: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font: 10px/10px Arial;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the circle diameter, you change the CSS, e.g.

```
.box-view {
  width: 60px; height: 60px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px;    
}

.box {
  border-radius: 300px;
  width: 40px; height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font: 10px/10px Arial;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

To change the text displayed, you change the template:

```
<script type="x-template" id="underscore-template">
  <div class="box" id="box-<%= number %>" style="top: <%= top %>px; left: <%= left %>px; background: rgb(0,0,<%= color %>);">
    Count : <%= content %>       
  </div>
</script>
```

Finally, to make them move slower, you delay the call to the animation function:

```
var backboneAnimate = function() {
    for (var i = 0, l = boxes.length; i < l; i++) {
      boxes[i].tick();   
    }
    window.timeout = _.delay(_.defer, 50, backboneAnimate);
};
```

And the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Fr94w/

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me how to make the border of the circle alone to rotate instead of making the entire circle with text in to rotate....

Comment: You'd probably need to use a background element for the circle to move around and another element to contain the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.box-view {
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;    
}

.box {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font: 10px/40px Arial;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9sc4Q/